# How to display/hide textboxes upon changing values of select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on a project where user have facility to enter his record , I want to know about how to display or hide textboxes while changing select box values

Here I have a select box named with marital status

Options for  marital status are : 'married' and 'un-married'.

Here is the code:

```
<select class="form-control" name="Personal_Family_Marital_Status" id="Personal_Family_Marital_Status" style = "color:  black;" required>
    <option value="">Please Select Marital Status</option>
    <option value="Married">Married</option>
    <option value="Un-Married">Un-Married</option>
</select>
<div class = "form-group col-md-3">
    <label for = "cc-payment" class = "control-label mb-1">Spouse Name</label>
    <input type = "text" autocomplete="off" class = "form-control"  name="Persoanl_Family_Spouse_Name" id = "Persoanl_Family_Spouse_Name"   style = "color:  black;" value="" placeholder="Mention your Spouse Name" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Mention your Spouse Name if Applicable" required />
</div>
```

If user selects 'Married' from above options, then a textbox appear for entering Spouse name

If user select  'Un-Married' from above option then a spouse name textbox should disappear.

Comment: What code have you tried to achieve this? (As a hint to get started, you will need an event listener for the `change` event on your `<select>` element.)

Comment: i try this but when i change my value from select box it will not call jquery 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
 
$("#Personal_Family_Marital_Status").on("change", function() {
 alert("in");
  var input = $("#Persoanl_Family_Spouse_Name");
  var readonly = !(this.value === "Married");
  input.prop("readonly", readonly);
  input.prop("required", !readonly);
});

</script>

Comment: Did you remember to wrap the code in a `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may employ [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) / [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) methods for that purpose:

```js
$('[name="Personal_Family_Marital_Status"]').on('change', function(){
  $(this).val() == 'Married' ? $('#spouse').show() : $('#spouse').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="Personal_Family_Marital_Status" id="Personal_Family_Marital_Status" style = "color:  black;" required>
 <option value="">Please Select Marital Status</option>
 <option value="Married">Married</option>
 <option value="Un-Married">Single</option>
</select>
<div id="spouse" class = "form-group col-md-3" style="display:none">
 <label for = "cc-payment" class = "control-label mb-1">Spouse Name</label>
 <input type = "text" autocomplete="off" class = "form-control"  name="Persoanl_Family_Spouse_Name" id = "Persoanl_Family_Spouse_Name"   style = "color:  black;" value="" placeholder="Mention your Spouse Name" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Mention your Spouse Name if Applicable" required />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

but where to add these lines:
$('[name="Personal_Family_Marital_Status"]').on('change', function(){
  $(this).val() == 'Married' ? $('#spouse').show() : $('#spouse').hide();
});

Comment: You may incorporate the code between `<script type="application/javascript"></script>` at your HTML markup right next to 'spouse' `<div>`

Comment: However, if there's more interaction with the page you might require, I would suggest to create separate .js file and refer to that within `<head>` section of your web page, like this: `<script type="application/javascript" src="/js/file/location/at/your/server"></script>`

Comment: You're quite welcome. If your problem is solved, you may accept the answer.

Comment: yes my problem solved done

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery `change` event for select ,hopee this helps,thanks

```js
$("#Personal_Family_Marital_Status").change(function(e){

if($(this).val()=='Married')
{
  $('.hide').addClass('show').removeClass('hide')
}
else
$('.show').addClass('hide').removeClass('show')

})
```

```css
 .hide
 {
 display:none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="Personal_Family_Marital_Status" id="Personal_Family_Marital_Status"   required>
<option value="">Please Select Marital Status</option>                         <option value="Married">Married</option>
<option value="Un-Married">Unmarried</option>
</select>


 <div class = "form-group col-md-3 hide">
<label for = "cc-payment" class = "control-label mb-1">Spouse Name</label>
<input type = "text" autocomplete="off" class = "form-control "  name="Persoanl_Family_Spouse_Name" id = "Persoanl_Family_Spouse_Name"   style = "color:  black;"   placeholder="Mention your Spouse Name" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Mention your Spouse Name if Applicable" required />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have included jQuery.

```
<select class="form-control" name="Personal_Family_Marital_Status" id="Personal_Family_Marital_Status" style = "color:  black;" required>
    <option value="">Please Select Marital Status</option>
    <option value="Married"></option>
    <option value="Un-Married"></option>
</select>


<div class="form-group col-md-3 hidden" id="spouseNameBlock">
    <label for = "cc-payment" class = "control-label mb-1">Spouse Name</label>
    <input type = "text" autocomplete="off" class = "form-control"  name="Persoanl_Family_Spouse_Name" id = "Persoanl_Family_Spouse_Name"   style = "color:  black;" value="<?php echo $data['Persoanl_Family_Spouse_Name'];?>"  placeholder="Mention your Spouse Name" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Mention your Spouse Name if Applicable" required />
</div>


<script>
    $('#Personal_Family_Marital_Status').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() === 'Married'){
            $('#spouseNameBlock').removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $('#spouseNameBlock').addClass('hidden');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to take advantage of the `display` and `visibility` properties in CSS. I'll use Vanilla JavaScript instead of jQuery to access the DOM. In your example:

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" name="Personal_Family_Marital_Status" id="Personal_Family_Marital_Status" style = "color:  black;" required>
   <option id="Select" value="">Please Select Marital Status</option>
   <option id="Married" value="Married"></option>
   <option id="UnMarried" value="Un-Married"></option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="SpouseName">
```

Vanilla JavaScript:

```
if (document.getElementById("Married").selected == true)
{
    document.getElementById("SpouseName").style = "display: block; visibility: visible";
}
if (document.getElementById("UnMarried").selected == true)
{
    document.getElementById("SpouseName").style = "display: none; visibility: hidden";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to make use of the `change` event on the select element. Based on its value, you can show / hide the spouse section

> The change event is fired for , , and  elements when an alteration to the element's value is committed by the user. Unlike the input event, the change event is not necessarily fired for each alteration to an element's value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

```js
var ddMaritalStatus = document.getElementById("Personal_Family_Marital_Status");
var fgSpouse = document.getElementById("fgSpouse");

ddMaritalStatus.addEventListener("change", function() {
  fgSpouse.style.display = this.value === 'Married' ? 'block' : 'none';
})
```

```html
<select class="form-control" name="Personal_Family_Marital_Status" id="Personal_Family_Marital_Status" style="color:  black;" required>
  <option value="">Please Select Marital Status</option>
  <option value="Married">Married</option>
  <option value="Un-Married">Un Married</option>
</select>


<div id="fgSpouse" class="form-group col-md-3" style="display:none">
  <label for="cc-payment" class="control-label mb-1">Spouse Name</label>
  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" name="Persoanl_Family_Spouse_Name" id="Persoanl_Family_Spouse_Name" style="color:  black;" value="" placeholder="Mention your Spouse Name" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Mention your Spouse Name if Applicable"
    required />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using a Jquery change function

```js
$("#Personal_Family_Marital_Status").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == "Married")
    $("#id_spouse").show();
  else
    $("#id_spouse").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="Personal_Family_Marital_Status" id="Personal_Family_Marital_Status" style = "color:  black;" required>
  <option value="">Please Select Marital Status</option>      
  <option value="Married">Married</option>
  <option value="Un-Married">Un-Married</option>
</select>


<div class = "form-group col-md-3">
  <div id="id_spouse" style="display:none">
    <label for = "cc-payment" class = "control-label mb-1">Spouse Name</label>
    <input type = "text" autocomplete="off" class = "form-control"  name="Persoanl_Family_Spouse_Name" id = "Persoanl_Family_Spouse_Name"   style = "color:  black;" value=""  placeholder="Mention your Spouse Name" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Mention your Spouse Name if Applicable" required />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
**You can use jquery onchange function.**  

 $(document).on('change','#Personal_Family_Marital_Status', function(){
              if($(this).val()=='Married'){
                $('#Spouse').show();
              }else{
                $('#Spouse').hide();
              }
            });


     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>     
    <select class="form-control" name="Personal_Family_Marital_Status" id="Personal_Family_Marital_Status" style="color:black;" required>
                <option value="">Please Select Marital Status</option>         
                <option value="Married">Married</option>
                <option value="Un-Married">Un-Married</option>
            </select>
            <div class = "form-group col-md-3" id="Spouse" style="display:none;">
            <label for = "cc-payment" class = "control-label mb-1">Spouse Name</label>
            <input type = "text" autocomplete="off" class = "form-control"  name="Persoanl_Family_Spouse_Name" id = "Persoanl_Family_Spouse_Name"   style = "color:  black;" value="<?php echo $data['Persoanl_Family_Spouse_Name'];?>"  placeholder="Mention your Spouse Name" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Mention your Spouse Name if Applicable" required />
            </div>
```